# Is there a function to stop printing something in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to code a program that finds searches for a string in a text file, and if the given string is within the text file, it shows 'That nickname is taken.' However, after each line which no text has been entered, a line of irrelavant text shows. Here is my code:`

```
nick_idea = input('Nickname idea: ')
if nick_idea in open('class.txt').read():
    print ('That name is already taken!')
else:
    print('Great Name!')
while nick_idea != '':
    nick_idea = input('Nickname idea: ')
    if nick_idea in open('class.txt').read():
        print ('That name is already taken!')
    else:
        print('Great Name!')`
```

Comment: Hey, can you please explain your problem properly? I am having difficulty in understanding your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking if an empty string `''` is in another string will always return True, so it will print that the name is already taken. Include a statment to check for that case. Additionally, you shouldn't need to open the file more than once.

```
with open('class.txt') as file:
    nicknames = file.read()

while True:
    nick_idea = input('Nickname idea: ')
    if not nick_idea:
        break
    elif nick_idea in nicknames:
        print('That name is already taken!')
    else:
        print('Great Name!')
```